# Convert a matrix in graph

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, graph

I have a problem in Java.I must create a graph. For input I have a `char[][]`.
The graph has this proprerty:
Give an char's matrix and we suppose that this is in position `[i][j]`.
Then I have a Node in the graph that represent this position.
The node that represent the position `[i][j]` has an edge with the node that represent(if possible):

1. the position'[i+1][j]'
2. the position '[i-1][j]'
3. the position'[i][j+1]'
4. The position'[i][j-1]'

But I have a problem in through the matrix and create an edge with this property. I think so I use a recursive algorithm. It's correct?
Thank to all

Comment: what is the problem that you have?

Comment: Cleaned up the grammar and spelling, formatted "code" things to make them stand out.

Comment: ok i have this problem:

Comment: My problem is build the graph.

Comment: Are you trying to build a representation of a [grid graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GridGraph.html)? What do you need the `char[][]` for, except dimensions?

Comment: Yes, i need of representation of the grid graph. The grid graph must be the representation of char[][] that i have in input

Comment: You can interpret any two-dimensional rectangular array `a[][]` as a grid graph already, where  `a[i][j]` and `a[r][s]` are adjacent if and only if `|i-r| + |j-s| = 1`.